# How do I package a bridged network VirtualBox box in Vagrant?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vagrant

When I try to package a VirtualBox with bridged networking, it loses the bridged network attribute and always reverts to NAT. Not even the 2nd interface is bridged network. I tried the Vagrant Google Group, and they suggested to edit the Vagrant file directly in `C:\Users\Chloe\.vagrant.d\boxes\nycmesh-qmp-openwrt\0\virtualbox\Vagrantfile`. I tried to add `config.vm.network "public_network"` but when I ran `vagrant up` it gave this

> Warnings:
>   * Unknown network type 'public_network' will be ignored.

and it also didn't generate a bridged network in VirtualBox.

Vagrant 1.9.2